# Angular: Subject behaviour different when using forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Folks, can anyone explain this behaviour?

This is working:

```
this.sessionService.current$.subscribe(session => { console.log('WORKING', session); });
```

But this is NOT working:

```
forkJoin([
      this.sessionService.current$
    ])
      .subscribe(([
        session
      ]) => {
        console.log('NOT WORKING', session);
...
```

After a little change got it working:

```
forkJoin([
      this.sessionService.current$.pipe(take(1))
    ])
      .subscribe(([
        session
      ]) => {
        console.log('WORKING', session);
...
```

current$ property in SessionService is defined like this:

```
private readonly subject$: Subject<Session> = new BehaviorSubject<Session>(null);
public readonly current$: Observable<Session> = this.subject$.asObservable();
```

there is then a `init()` method where I `GET` data over http and emit to `this.subject$`;

Thanks a lot for a right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits only after all its source Observables emit at least once and all complete. So when you're using `Subject` as a source Observable for `forkJoin()` then by adding `take(1)` you force it to complete and therefore `forkJoin` emits as well and then completes.

Comment: Thanks! So, as far as I understand, forkJoin should be a cold observable and does not require an unsubscribe then?

Comment: @Luke1988 forkJoin is often used with hot observables, just not with long-lived observables. Also, you should unsubscribe if there's a chance an inner observable may not complete or if you want to unsubscribe from the inner Observables because you're no longer interested in the result from forkJoin.

Comment: In current situation forkJoin makes absolutely no sense. Usually there is 2 or more observables and all except sessionService.current$ are cold http observables that fetch data from API. It makes sense then to wait until all observables finish because I need all the data to complete response. Therefore forkJoin. I wonder if unsubscribe from forkJoin subscription is required. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430898/8244989) explains why forkJoin unsubscribe is not required